# When i am trying to send mail from contactUS form getting this error using swiftmailer in Laravel 5.2

Tags: laravel, gmail, swiftmailer

when i am trying to send Mail through Contact Us Form receiving this Error

"Address in mailbox given [] does not comply with RFC 2822, 3.6.2."
I try search to find solution but I cannot find one. I edited config/mail.php

```
public function sendContactInfo(ContactMeRequest $request)
{
    $data = $request->only('name', 'email');
    $emailto="******@gmail.com";
    $data['messageLines'] = explode("\n", $request->get('message'));
    Mail::send('publicPages.contactus', $data, function ($message) use ($emailto) {

        $message->subject('Contact Us Form: ')
            ->to(config('blog.contact_email'))
            ->replyTo($data['email']);
    });

    return back()
        ->withSuccess("Thank you for your message. It has been sent.");
}
```

with configuration file

i am following this tutorial
[Laravel Send Mail](http://laravelcoding.com/blog/laravel-5-beauty-sending-mail-and-using-queues#14-contact-ctrl)

Comment: what is the version of your php

Comment: have you tried [PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer), its the best library i have ever found

Answer (score 0):

use $data['email']

```
   Mail::send('publicPages.contactus', $data, function ($message) use ($emailto,$data['email']) {

        $message->subject('Contact Us Form: ')
            ->to(config('blog.contact_email'))
            ->replyTo($data['email']);
    });
```

Comment: i was doing with $data['email'] earlier but the error was same..
that's why i stored email in a separate variable and use $emailto just to ensure email passed correctly

Comment: check mail.php.in that  'from' => ['address' =>null, 'name' =>null], must not be empty.assign values to from and name

Comment: error is coming through these lines of codes

`code`private function _assertValidAddress($address)
    {
        if (!preg_match('/^'.$this->getGrammar()->getDefinition('addr-spec').'$/D',
            $address)) {
            throw new Swift_RfcComplianceException(
                'Address in mailbox given ['.$address.
                '] does not comply with RFC 2822, 3.6.2.'
                );
        }
    }

Comment: Boora
i already try this out, while commenting that function app function stoped working
may be error coming because em using hard coded value in Config/mail.php file
<code>    

`'from' => ['address' => '********@gmail.com', 'name' => 'Wajahat Hashmi'],`


but when i was referring values from .env getting the same error